# Vertical lines in plot_fit graphic of python ststsmodels package

Tags: python, graphics, statsmodels

What are vertical lines in python `stats-models plot_fit` graphic as discussed here: [LINK](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_fit.html#statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_fit).

Plot output :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical lines are pointwise prediction intervals. Prediction intervals combine the estimation error for the parameters and the variance for the inherent noise to get the confidence interval for the observed response variable, i.e. Murder Rate in this case.

This is similar to the usual prediction confidence band. However, since this is a scatter plot of observed and predicted values based on all explanatory variables a confidence band does not "look good" in the multiple regression case.

As smoother version can be obtained by predictions that keep the other explanatory variables at fixed values, or in other regression plots.